# Laravel Database Migration Column altered to Unique and Nullable causing error

Tags: laravel, doctrine, migration, dbal

I am attempting to integrate social logins with my existing laravel app. I am attempting to change email and password to nullable but I also need email to remain unique. On executing my migration I am getting an error for duplicate key name 'users_email_unique'

Laravel 5, already fixed the issue with enum I had for altering a column.

```
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable()->change();
        $table->string('password')->nullable()->change();
    });
```

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'users_email_unique' (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

Exception trace:

1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'users_email_unique'")

/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:119

2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'users_email_unique'")

/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117

**Edit**

If I remove Unique() from email, will it remain unique since that was previously set in a different migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out myself, as mentioned in the comment on the above answer.

Simply because the table was already created with unique() if I remove that it will allow the migration and will also persist the unique() functionality that was in the original User table migration.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the uniqueness behaviour in a new migration by following below:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique(['email']);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *     
*/
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('email')->unique()->change();
    });
}
```

The `Nullable()` attribute will stay with the `email` column, since it was created with it.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like the database is detecting a repeated value. That's impossible with nulls, so it could be an empty string maybe.

If that's the case, you can write a mutator function in your model to check if the value is empty and, set it to null before it goes to the database engine, like this:

```
public function setNameOfYourAttribute($value) {
    if ( empty($value) ) {
        $this->attributes['nameofyourattribute'] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

NOTE:
[Full Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: if I 
'change $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable()->change();'
to
'$table->string('email')->nullable()->change();' then it works fine but scared it loses the unique attribute that was in the original migration for the model that I am editing